# WordPress image editor broken when using S3 Offload Lite plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I'm using the [WP Offload S3 Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) plugin on my Wordpress site. Uploading and creating the thumbnails seems to work fine, but when I try to edit the image using WP's built-in image editor, it displays a broken image:

[image]

How can I fix this error?

My nginx error log shows:

`2016/11/05 16:10:44 [error] 6767#0: *164466 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WPOS3: There was an error attempting to download the file store/2016/11/forests-why-matter_63516847.jpg from S3: The local directory /home/avishai/apps/myapp/releases/20161105032906/public/wp-content/uploads/2016/11 does not exist and could not be created.
PHP message: WPOS3: File /home/avishai/apps/myapp/releases/20161105032906/public/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/forests-why-matter_63516847.jpg does not exist" while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.162.219.242, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=regenerate-thumbnails&goback=1&ids=14309&_wpnonce=fd0b4e4dab"`

My server has those directories `chown`ed by the nginx user, and is writeable.

Comment: did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the required image editing libraries on your host system. If you are running PHP7, try adding the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
sudo service apache2 restart
```